# Custom MKAnnotation dictionary input (CLLocationCoordinate2d)

Tags: swift, dictionary, mapkit, mkannotation

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class Point: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var id: String?
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var subtitle: String?



    init(id: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){


        self.id = id

        if let title = dictionary["title"] as? String {
            self.title = title
        }

        if let subtitle = dictionary["subtitle"] as? String {
            self.subtitle = subtitle
        }

        if let coords = dictionary["coordinates"] as? [String:[String:Double]] {
            var latitude = coords.values.first!["latitude"]!
            var longitude = coords.values.first!["longitude"]!
            var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            self.coordinate = location
        }

    }
```

Error: property self.coordinate not initialized at implicitly generated super.init call.

Any Idea how to solve this?

Thanks for some advice.

Comment: first line of your custom constructor should be "super.init()" [that is exactly what error's message is telling you]

Comment: I am adding this line but it writes same error: Property self.coordinate not initialized at super.init call

Comment: Because `coordinate` is not an Optional, it has to be initialized for every branch of the control flow.

Comment: var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(), but are you sure on what are you doing? MKAnnotation already have an attribute 'coordinate'..

Comment: I am using Firebase and output from Firebase are Dictionary and I need all keys from dictionary and set values.

Answer (score 0):

Either you should assign a default value in else case of

```
if let coords = dictionary["coordinates"] as? [String:[String:Double]] {
...
} else {
self.coordinate = <assign a default location>
}
```

Or

You should not create object if no coordinates. So make your init optional.

```
 init?(id: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){

      if let coords = dictionary["coordinates"] as? [String:[String:Double]] {
           self.id = id

           if let title = dictionary["title"] as? String {
                self.title = title
           }

           if let subtitle = dictionary["subtitle"] as? String {
                self.subtitle = subtitle
           }
           var latitude = coords.values.first!["latitude"]!
           var longitude = coords.values.first!["longitude"]!
           var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
           self.coordinate = location
      } else {
           return nil
      }
 }
```